# Making a Linux live CD bootable from Compact Flash (CF)?

Tags: linux, flash, bootable-media, livecd

Making a live CD using tools such as livecd-creator seems like a good solution to create a bootable read-only image to install on Compact Flash.  My goal is to prevent failure due to write cycle limits of Compact Flash memory.  A secondary goal is to have the live CD available for troubleshooting.

However, Usenet postings indicate challenges in making the live CD image on CF bootable.  Has anyone succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu on my DSLR, I used [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Okay, amuse me. *Why* would you put Linux on a DSLR?

Comment: PenTesting, very fast.  Actually, one day the camera was the only option for a live boot.  I haven't considered R/W cycles, those cards are cheaper every day. BTW I've learned a lot with your answers in SO.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something I've tried yet, so I can't help specifically. You're running uphill by choosing formats that rarely appear  out there; USB is what unetbootin thrives in.

Anyway, I [found a wiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Flash_boot_drive) for Thinkpad / Windows CF booting. You might learn a thing or two about 10k and 100k-write durability designs, general tuning tips and even the fixed disk  /  removable disk issues that can translate to your purposes. The hardest part is probably going to be ensuring that current USB tools like unetbooting read your CF card. Next hardest will probably be even **finding** motherboards trying to even offer booting for CF.

When manufacturers fail to provide a standard and users fail to demand one (I think that's how el-torito **bootable CD's** and even **bootable USB** support came about). Your request sounds like a roll-your-own solution kind-of thing, which is hard to do unless you're a hardware hacker with means to solder things together and program new logic into chips. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[MEMDISK](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK) will allow you to load a [bootable ISO image](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK#ISO_images) from certain bootloaders.